# Protractor-Cucumber: how to generate HTML report

Tags: report, cucumber, protractor

After add line `resultJsonOutputFile: 'report.json',` to config file and run my test in Webstorm, there is a `report.json` created but there is no content on it. I don't know what's the reason.

Please help me to expland why my `report.json` has no content? And how to generate Html report for my test?

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Serenity/JS](http://serenity-js.org), which can compliment your current Protractor/Cucumber setup to generate illustrated HTML reports automatically - [see this answer for instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34821016/is-there-a-protractor-reporting-tool-that-works-with-a-cucumber-framework/42598696#42598696)

Answer (score 1):

Use `cucumber-html-report` You might want to have a look at this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33739439/790950

Make sure you add the code snippet to your `features/support/hooks.js` file and also load that file as part of your `protractor.conf` file:

```
cucumberOpts: {
    require: [
      '../e2e/features/**/steps/*.js',
      '../e2e/features/support/hooks.js',
    ],
    format: 'pretty',
  },
```

Notice that you don't have to change the console format as it does it dynamically. Also adds screenshots in case of failures.