# Attach screenshot to cucumber-html-reporter using cucumber-tsflow and protractor

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber

After every failed scenario, I would like to attach a screenshot to html report (generated by [cucumber-html-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cucumber-html-reporter), using [cucumber-tsflow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cucumber-tsflow) and [protractor](https://www.protractortest.org/#/). Is that possible?

As far as I understand, I don't have access to the `world` instance anymore when writing the steps using [cucumber-tsflow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cucumber-tsflow). Otherwise something like `this.attach(screenshot, 'image/png');` would have done the trick.

After googling for a while, I saw some people attaching the screenshot to the scenario like `scenario.attach(screenshot);`. However, the scenario I get in `@after()`(hook) is an instance of `HookScenarioResult`. That interface does not have any method to attach a file to.

I placed a simplified snippet code of the step.ts and conf.ts below. I tried to attach the screenshot in the `afterAllScenarios()` method with no succes. Hopefully someone can help me out with my problem.

**samplestep-definition.ts**

```js
import { binding, given, then, when, before, after } from 'cucumber-tsflow';
import { browser } from 'protractor';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { HookScenarioResult, Status } from 'cucumber';

import HomePage from './page-objects/home-page';

@binding()
export class HomePageSteps {
    private homePage = new HomePage();

    @before()
    public beforeAllScenarios(): void {
        browser.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @given(/the user is at the home page/)
    public async givenUserAtHomePage(): Promise<void> {
        await this.homePage.get();
        const actual = await browser.getCurrentUrl();
        const expected = 'https://qaclickacademy.github.io/protocommerce/';
        expect(actual).to.equal(expected);
    }

    @when(/the user enters (.*) in the name field/)
    public async userEntersNameField(input: string): Promise<void> {
        await this.homePage.typeNameAndTab(input);
    }

    @then(/the user should see error message (.*)/)
    public async useShouldSeeErrorMessage(message: string) {
        const errorMessage = await this.homePage.getErrorMessage();
        expect(errorMessage).to.equal(message);
    }

    @after()
    public async afterAllScenarios(scenario: HookScenarioResult): Promise<void> {
        if (scenario.result.status === Status.PASSED) {
            const screenshot = await browser.takeScreenshot();
            // No access to World instance so the code below won't work
            this.attach(screenshot, "image/png");

            // HookScenario has no attach method, so the code below won't work
            scenario.attach(screenshot);
        }
    }
}
```

**cucumber-config.ts**

```js
import { Config } from 'protractor';
import * as reporter from 'cucumber-html-reporter';

// An example configuration file
export let config: Config = {
  directConnect: true,
  framework: 'custom',
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
  },
  specs: ['../features/sample.feature'],

  cucumberOpts: {
    format: 'json:./report/cucumber_report.json',
    tags: [
      '@smoketesting'
    ]
  },

  onComplete: () => {
    console.log('on complete called');
    var options = {
      theme: 'bootstrap',
      jsonFile: './report/cucumber_report.json',
      output: './report/cucumber_report.html',
      reportSuiteAsScenarios: true,
      scenarioTimestamp: true,
      launchReport: true,
      metadata: {
        "App Version": "0.3.2"
      }
    };

    reporter.generate(options);
  }
};
```

Comment: I kinda have same issue, except I don't use cucumber-tsflow... In my case I manually wrote a World.ts, containing a home-made attach() method, that does nothing else but creating the screenshots in the test folder... So did you manage this problem, if yes I would like to know how :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just use somethig like that, set argument **this: World**
and connect it here, without custom code
import { World } from "@cucumber/cucumber";

```
import { browser } from "protractor";
import { AfterAll, After, Status, World } from "@cucumber/cucumber";
import { setDefaultTimeout } from "@cucumber/cucumber";

setDefaultTimeout(60 * 1000);

After(async function (this: World, scenario) {
  if (scenario.result?.status === Status.PASSED) {
    const screenShot = await browser.takeScreenshot();
    this.attach(screenShot , "image/png");
  }
});
```

Comment: works for me for playwright too: ```    if (Scenario.result!.status === Status.FAILED) {
        const buffer = await page.screenshot({
            path: `./Screenshots/error - ${scnName}.png`,
            fullPage: true
        })        
        this.attach(buffer, 'image/png')
    } 

    await page.close();```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have a custom World you need to make sure that the constructor utilize the attach property. I don't know how it's done with cucumber-tsflow, but cucumberjs which used internally by cucumber-tsflow need the attach parameter like this :

```js
function World({ attach }) {
  this.attach = attach
}
```

2. We use a custom world in typescript for our Angular E2E test app
   Here's a cut of the file

```js
// world.ts
const { setWorldConstructor } = require('cucumber');

export class World {
  private attach: (buffer: Buffer, mimeType: string) => void;
  constructor({ attach }) {
    this.attach = attach;
  }
}
```

And then in the hook.ts

```js
import { browser } from 'protractor';
import { HookScenarioResult } from 'cucumber';
const { Before, After } = require('cucumber');

// hook.ts
After(async function(scenario: HookScenarioResult) {
  const ss = await browser.takeScreenshot();
  const img = Buffer.alloc(ss.length, ss, 'base64');
  this.attach(img, 'image/png');
});
```

Also, apparently you have a way to use the world's constructor parameter: https://github.com/timjroberts/cucumber-js-tsflow/issues/16