# protractor is not capturing the Screenshot with Cucumber Reporter

Tags: protractor, cucumber

i am using Protractor with Cucumber to test angular application, for reporting i am using "cucumber-html-reporter", i am not able to capture the screenshot in report and its not getting saved in the given folder as well

reporter.js

```
const reporter = require("cucumber-html-reporter");
cucumberReporteroptions = {
  theme: "bootstrap",
  //jsonFile: targetJson,
  jsonDir: targetjsonDir,
  output: htmlReports + "/cucumber_reporter"+datetime+".html",
  reportSuiteAsScenarios: true,
  storeScreenshots:true,
  screenshotsDirectory:htmlReports +'/screenshots',
  reportSuiteAsScenarios:true,
  launchReport:true,
  ignoreBadJsonFile:true
};

class Reporter {

  static createHTMLReport() {
    try {
      reporter.generate(cucumberReporteroptions); //invoke cucumber-html-reporter
    } catch (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Failed to save cucumber test results to json file.");
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  }
```

hooks.js

```
 After(function(scenario) {
            const attach = this.attach; 
            return browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(png) {
              const decodedImage = new Buffer(png, "base64");
              return attach(decodedImage, "image/png");
            });
        });
```

Comment: Are you trying to capture the screenshot only for failure scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

Quick checks that you can do from your side, to make sure reporter is invoked properly:

```
onPrepare: () => {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.manage().window().maximize();
    Reporter.createDirectory(jsonReports);
},
cucumberOpts: {
    compiler: "ts:ts-node/register",
    format: "json:./reports/json/cucumber_report.json",
    require: ["../../typeScript/stepdefinitions/*.js", "../../typeScript/support/*.js"],
    strict: true,
},

onComplete: () => {
    Reporter.createHTMLReport();
},
```

Can you try this,

```
defineSupportCode(({After}) => {
    After(function(scenario) {
        if (scenario.isFailed()) {
        var attach = this.attach; 
        return browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(png) {
        var decodedImage = new Buffer(png, "base64");
        return attach(decodedImage, "image/png");
      });
     }
   });
});
```

Lemme know how it goes!

Comment: Hello, when i execute this code, i get a screenshot generated inside the report folder. But nothing is attached to the HTML report itself. [this.attach] calls a "attach" function from world.ts right ? I can't find NOWHERE an exemple of this function. I'd appreciate if you hade one :)

Comment: Nevermind I found a solution. Explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60278678/2376892